# Как правильно отобразить не модальную форму загрузки во время сохранения файла в отдельном потоке?

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Опыт в C# не большой, просьба не отсылать на MSDN-ы.

Проблема состоит в том что после запуска процедуры сохранения данных из `DataGridView` в файл **MS Word** в фоновом режиме, форма с прогресс баром *"Пожалуйста подождите"* - зависает. Необходимо вывести именно форму загрузки т.к. на первой форме реализован фильтр для `DataGridView` и при внесении изменений в фильтр, сохранение заканчивается ошибкой. Помогите найти решение!

```
case 2:
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => Save2Word(sfd));
    Thread winThread = new Thread(() => showAwaitWindow(thread1));
    thread1.IsBackground = true;
    winThread.IsBackground = true;
    thread1.Start();
    winThread.Start();                        
    break;
```

Далее код открытия формы загрузки:

```
private void showAwaitWindow(Thread t1)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show();
    f2.pBar1.Visible = true;

    while (t1.IsAlive)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    f2.Close();
}
```

Comment: Неплохо бы отделить отображение данных (грид) от их модели хранения. Синхронизацию модели с отображением можно было бы блокировать на время сохранения в файл.

Comment: @free_ze, отображение данных в гриде выполнено с помощью DataView, а блокировать ДГВ нельзя по тех заданию :( Необходима именно форма загрузки.

Comment: Выхода нет - нужно кэшировать данные на момент принятия решения о сохранении. Более адекватное решение - разделять хранение от представления и обновлять модель хранения при необходимости.

Comment: Вы какую версию .Net используете?

Comment: @Bulson, .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: А каким образом вы получаете сообщения о прогрессе операции? Это важно.

Comment: @VladD, progressBar на форме загрузки имеет стиль Marquee,поэтому  отслеживать состояние не нужно. А вот проверка на то, работает ли поток или нет в данный момент проверяю с помощью свойства Thread.IsAlive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пойдем по порядку. `case 2:...break;` здесь лучше избегать больших блоков кода, если действительно требуется - выносите это всё в отдельный метод, тогда будет `case 2: await WriteToFile(); break;`. Метод, который пишет в файл не должен быть `void`, он должен возвращать `bool`, иначе вы теряете связность, такой код тяжело дебажить. Примерно ваш `Save2Word(sfd)` должен быть таким:

```
private bool Save2Word(какой-то-тип sfd)
{
    try
    {
        //здесь пишем в файл
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //здесь пишем в лог или Debug.WriteLine()
        return false;
    }
}
```

Тогда должно быть примерно так

```
private async Task WriteToFile()
{
    //занимаем пользователя
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show();

    //пишем в файл и ждем результат
    bool result = await Task.Run<bool>(() =>
        {
            var res = Save2Word();
            return res;
        });

    if (!result)
    {
        //не получилось записать
        //прячем f2 и сообщаем радостную весть пользователю
    }

    //прячем f2 и делаем другую полезную работу
}
```

Comment: сделал всё как описано у Вас в примере, всплывающая форма прорисовывается, но всё равно в повисшем состоянии ((

Comment: @heavenbeyond91 Что значит в повисшем состоянии? В файл пишет нормально?

Comment: @heavenbeyond91 если вам мой ответ не помог, то не торопитесь закрывать вопрос, может еще кто подтянется, снимите галку.

Comment: Да, в файл записывает нормально, форма прорисовывается, но прогресс бар начинает работать только после сохранения файла.

Comment: @heavenbeyond91 изменил ответ, попробуйте так

Comment: В чем смысл запуска в отдельном потоке функции `Save2Word()`? Если она синхронная, то зачем тогда возвращает `Task`? Лучше всего сделать ее по-настоящему асинхронной и вызывать без всяких `Task.Run()`.

Comment: @heavenbeyond91 изменил еще Save2Word - уберите там асинхронность. Должно так работать, у меня работает нормально.

Comment: @Bulson, Всё работает. Большая Вам благодарность !!

Comment: @heavenbeyond91 рад помочь, видите, я и сам немного слажал сначала :)